# Using paypal IPN to send a random string via EMAIL

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-ipn

Ok I'll cut to the chase, I have this code which produces a random string:

```
function random_string()
{      
    $character_set_array = array();

    //$character_set_array[] = array('count' => 2, 'characters' => 'AA');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 8, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    $pinstart = 'AA';
    $pinend = implode('', $temp_array);
    $pin = $pinstart.$pinend;
    echo $pin;
}
```

Then in my paypal IPN I have this:

```
if($p->ipn_data["mc_gross"] > 0 && strcmp ($p->ipn_data["business"],$EMAIL) == 0 && ($p->ipn_data["item_number"]) == 1)  {
         $user = $p->ipn_data["custom"];
             $date = $p->ipn_data["payment_date"];
             $prodid = $p->ipn_data["item_number"];
             $amount = $p->ipn_data["mc_gross"];
             $amountTickets = 1;
             $email = 'email@hotmail.com';
             $subject = '[CODE] - Thank you for your donation';
             $message = 'Your CODE IS, <? echo random_string(); ?>';
             mail("$payer_email", "$subject",
             $message.random_string(), "From: $email" );
             $user = str_replace("_", " ", $user);
             $user = str_replace("-", " ", $user);
             $user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);

         }
```

It sends the email but its "Your CODE is, , it doesn't post the random string.

I've tried putting in $pin, $pin = random_string(); print $pin nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `echo $pin;` to `return $pin` in your `random_string` function because you want it to return a string, not to print out a string on the spot, then

```
$message = 'Your CODE IS, ' . random_string();
```

Answer (score 0):

random_string should use return not echo

then

```
...
 $subject = '[CODE] - Thank you for your donation';
  $message = 'Your CODE IS,'. random_string();
  mail("$payer_email", "$subject",
...
```

Comment: Thank you both answers helped